# Get minimal geo distance from joined table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, postgis

I have two tables *projects* and *locations*. A project can have many locations by use of the *locations.project_id* reference. Furthermore, locations feature the columns *locations.latitude* and *locations.longitude*.

I'm now looking for an efficient way to query all projects and their minimal distance to a fixed point. Say, there are two projects in the table each with two locations, I'd like to get the two projects and the distance to the one location which is closest to the fixed point.

I've created a `.geography` function for convenience:

```
CREATE FUNCTION geography(locations) RETURNS GEOGRAPHY AS $$
  SELECT ST_GeographyFromText(
    'SRID=4326;POINT(' || $1.latitude || ' ' || $1.longitude || ')'
  )
$$ LANGUAGE SQL
```

Now the following example uses "Zurich (47.36865, 8.539183)" as the fixed point:

```
SELECT 
  ST_Distance(locations.geography, ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(47.36865 8.539183)')) AS distance 
  FROM "projects"
  INNER JOIN "locations" ON "locations"."project_id" = "projects"."id"
```

The query works, however, it returns the distance to the location with the oldest creation date and not the nearest one. Any idea how to tackle this?

**UPDATE**

My question is all wrong. What I try to achieve is quite easy with CTE, but that's another story. My apologies for the noise.

Comment: I don't totally follow your question. Where does creation date fit into the table and query. Are you saying you have two identical locations, but for creation date, and you only want the newest?

Comment: @JohnBarça If a project has more than one location, the INNER JOIN apparently only works on the one which comes first in the database (usually the oldest one) and calculates the distance. If I create first a location far away from the fixed point and then another one much closed to the fixed point, the above query will return the large distance since it was added first. I need the shortest distance no matter when it was inserted.

Comment: Order by st_distance(...) desc?

Answer (score 1):

PostGIS uses the axis order: longitude, latitude (think X, Y). Your distances are probably not what you expect, as you are currently searching in Somalia, not Switzerland.

Furthermore, your approach is really inefficient, since you are constantly re-generation `geography` types and have no spatial index. Consider moving the data into a spatial type, and removing redundant columns, e.g.:

```
ALTER TABLE locations ADD COLUMN geog geography(Point,4326);
UPDATE locations SET
    geog=ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude), 4326)::geography;
CREATE INDEX locations_geog_idx ON locations USING gist (geog);
ALTER TABLE locations DROP COLUMN latitude;
ALTER TABLE locations DROP COLUMN longitude;
```

You can always access and view the data using `ST_X` for longitude, or `ST_AsText` or `ST_AsLatLonText(geog::geometry)` for strings like 47°22'7.140"N 8°32'21.059"E. Now your query:

```
SELECT 
  ST_Distance(locations.geog,
              ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(8.539183, 47.36865), 4326)::geography)'))
    AS distance 
FROM "projects"
INNER JOIN "locations" ON "locations"."project_id" = "projects"."id";
```

Comment: You're right about the long/lat order, howere, this happened when I slimmed down the real case to this example. There's also an index on it. I'm upping your answer anyways to thank for your elaborate and correct answer - just my question is wrong.